# Looking for assistance with adding a randomizer to my search results

Tags: javascript, discord, bots, google-image-search

The purpose of this code is to run a bot on a Discord server. Right now it is able to search for images, but I would like to randomize the results.

I have the following variable -
var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * search.results.length);
but I'm not sure that it's formatted correctly, or where exactly to put it.

So here is my code:

```
var cheerio = require("cheerio"); /* Used to extract html content, based on jQuery || install with npm install cheerio */
var request = require("request"); /* Used to make requests to URLs and fetch response  || install with npm install request */

var discord = require("discord.js");
var client = new discord.Client();


// Login into discord using bot token (do not share token with anyone!).
client.login("");

client.on("ready", function() {
    console.log("logged in");
});

client.on("message", function(message) {

    var parts = message.content.split(" "); 

    /* Simple command manager */
    if (parts[0] === "search.") { 

        // call the image function
        image(message, parts); // Pass requester message to image function

    }

});

function image(message, parts) {

    /* extract search query from message */

    var search = parts.slice(1).join(" "); 

    var options = {
        url: "http://results.dogpile.com/serp?qc=images&q=" + search,
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
            "Accept": "text/html",
            "User-Agent": "Chrome"
        }
    };
    request(options, function(error, response, responseBody) {
        if (error) {
            // handle error
            return;
        }

        $ = cheerio.load(responseBody); 
        
        var urls = new Array(links.length).fill(0).map((v, i) => links.eq(i).attr("href"));
        console.log(urls);
        if (!urls.length) {
            // Handle no results
            return;
        }

        // Send result
        message.channel.send( urls[0] );
    });

client.on('message', msg => {
  if (msg.content === 'ping') {
    msg.reply('pong');
} else if (msg.content === '') {
  msg.reply('');
} else if (msg.content === '') {
  msg.reply('');
} else if (msg.content === '') {
  msg.reply('');
} else if (msg.content === '') {
  msg.reply('');
}
});

}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are trying to get a random image out of the results you have fetched and stored in *var urls*. (If its something different, please expand your question)

Since you already have generated the variable *rnd* limited with a max value of results length.

You can return a random result, by changing the following line.

> message.channel.send( **urls[rnd]** );

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work with the following:

```
    message.channel.send( urls[Math.floor((Math.random() * 50) + 1)] );
```